# Get Android Unique Identification

Tags: java, android

How to get an Android Unique Identification, except for Hardware Serial Code, is there any way to obtain? Iv'e tried this

```
String AndroidID = Settings.Secure.getString(getContentResolver(), Settings.Secure.ANDROID_ID);
```

but im still looking for other way that been used by other developers.

Thank You.

Comment: What is good enough? Could you parhaps specify what kind of format you're looking for?

Comment: Im looking for another way to obtain Unique Number for android.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use the UUID (IMEI), which is a unique identifier for each phone. Something like this:

```
TelephonyManager telephonyManager = (TelephonyManager) getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE);
String myUUID = telephonyManager .getDeviceId();
```

Also, there is a well written article that discusses the issue of identifying individual app installations, which requires a means for unique device identification. In the article several means for identification are discussed. Here is the link: http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2011/03/identifying-app-installations.html

Comment: Does this code work only on installation process or its permanent identifier of device?

Comment: This is a hard coded unique identifier for your device that never changes.

Comment: This returns imei number of the phone. I have noticed in few phones if there is no Sim card getdeviceid() returns null

Answer (score 0):

I use the following implementation:

```
String deviceId = getDeviceId(context); // my custom method-generator (IMEI & ANDROID_ID used)
String myUUID = UUID.nameUUIDFromBytes(deviceId.getBytes("utf8")).toString();
```

For example:
deviceId = 8ee80a0e1812aa89cd48b952dc09c11104d81a85
myUUID = "89d41ec1-0aef-39f2-8ae7-7545be3cc522"

Comment: P.S. UUID.randomUUID().toString() returns different values. This implementation returns a constant value.